# Best practice / idioms in C# to create "case classes"

Tags: c#, inheritance, idioms

I have the following situation:

- The user can execute a number of different actions.
- I want to remember the actions taken in a List.
- To store each type of action, I need to store different parameters. (Let's say, an ID and a string for a *rename* action or a DateTime for a *start* action.)

I have been coding in Scala for a while, there I would write something like

```
abstract class Action
case class RenameAction(id: Int, newTitle: String) extends Action
case class StartAction(time: Instant) extends Action
```

so that I could then write functions like

```
def process(action: Action) = action match {
    case RenameAction(id, title) => ...
    case StartAction(time) => ...
}
```

My question is: What is the best practice / most idiomatic way to solve this in C#?

I'll describe some thoughts I have:

---

1st possibility: Direct translation

```
public abstract class Action
{
}

public sealed class RenameAction : Action
{
    public readonly int id;
    public readonly string title;

    public RenameAction(int id, string title)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }
}

public sealed class StartAction : Action
{
    public readonly DateTime time;

    public StartAction(DateTime time)
    {
        this.time = time;
    }
}

...

public void process(Action action)
{
    if (action is RenameAction)
    {
        RenameAction ra = action as RenameAction;
        ...
    }
    else if (action is StartAction)
    {
        StartAction sa = action as StartAction;
        ...
    }
}
```

This obviously works, but feels clunky to me.
(It's just a small private project without time pressure, and in those I like to write code that I'm happy about ;))

---

2nd possibility: Using an enum, I could do something like this:

```
public sealed class Action
{
    public readonly ActionType type;
    public readonly object[] parameters;

    public Action(ActionType type, params object[] parameters)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }
}

enum ActionType
{
    RENAME,
    START
}

...

public void process(Action action)
{
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case ActionType.RENAME:
            var id = action.parameters[0] as int;
            var title = action.parameters[1] as string;
            ...
            break;
        case ActionType.START:
            var time = action.parameters[0] as DateTime;
            ...
            break;
    }
}
```

This has the benefit that the number of action types is fixed, however the `object[] parameters` feels clunky again.

Comment: C# 7 added pattern matching (see the reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is), so you can in fact write a direct translation of your Scala code

Comment: C# 7 has the feature you want; look up "pattern matching".

Comment: @UnholySheep: Beat me to it by 15 seconds. :-)

Comment: Oh wow, you guys were fast =)

Comment: And good heavens **do not name your class `Action`**.  You will get it thoroughly conflated with `System.Action`.

Comment: If you want good FP-style support inside .net ecosystem, take a look into F#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the comments, C# 7 has pattern matching on types in switches. You could write

```
public void Process(MyAction action)
{
    if (action is RenameAction)
    {
        RenameAction ra = action as RenameAction;
        ...
    }
    else if (action is StartAction)
    {
        StartAction sa = action as StartAction;
        ...
    }
```

more concisely as

```
public void Process(MyAction action)
{
    switch(action) 
    {
      case RenameAction ra: 
        ...
      case StartAction sa:
        ...
      case null:
        ...
      default: 
        ...
    }
```

and so on.

Note that you can also add constraints:

```
case RenameAction ra when (ra.TargetName != null):
```

That said: switching on a set of possible subtypes is considered to be a poor programming practice by many, for some good reasons. Such as (1) if new subtypes are created, then every switch has to be updated, (2) if there's behaviour that varies by subtype then that behaviour should be captured in the subtype, not in code external to the subtype, and so on.

Comment: If this is poor practice, what do you recommend instead?

Comment: @Gabriel: That depends. The supposition of the question is that the original poster has created a list of user actions, and now wishes to "process" those actions. What is "processing"? Is it *executing* the action? Then why isn't the code which executes the action exposed in a abstract `Execute()` method on the base class?  Is it *logging* the action?  Then override `ToString` and hey, once again, you don't need to switch on the type.

Comment: @Gabriel: Now, suppose we have some more complex situation, like we're switching on laser beam vs bullet, and trying to determine the interaction with zombie vs robot; this is a *double dispatch problem* and it would typically be solved in C# via an implementation of the visitor pattern; that might embed a type switch as an implementation detail of the pattern, but you'd code against the pattern, not the switch.

Comment: Yes, I was probably trying to pose the question to generally. After some more thinking, I can probably refactor so that an action "processes" itself, which eliminates the problem. I learned something anyway, so thank you and I'll accept the answer :) (and thanks for the comment about not naming it "Action")

Comment: Got it. I asked because I use a lot of algebraic data types with pattern matching, and so far it seems to be a clean approach. (I'm not talking about C# obviously, more like Haskell and F#).

Comment: @Gabriel: OO languages like C# and FP languages like F# simply take contradictory views on the proper location of behaviour code.  The OO approach is to bind behaviour tightly to data, which is an implementation detail hidden in a type. The FP approach is to make data structures transparent and the behaviours are external functions that manipulate the data. Either approach is reasonable; you run into impedance mismatches when you combine them without due diligence.

Comment: Yes, your statement "switching on a set of possible subtypes is considered to be a poor programming practice" was specifically about some languages like C#. Now it is clear to me. Thank you.

Comment: @Gabriel: My understanding was that the question was about C#. C# doesn't have the feature that F#/Ocaml has where you can know at compile time whether a pattern match is exhaustive; if it did, then this coding technique would be a lot safer in C#.

Comment: @EricLippert The question is indeed about C#, but it also covers FP because OP is trying to mimic a common FP idiom into C#. Your statement was somewhat broad so I decided to ask for clarification. Nothing wrong at all in your answer. BTW I thought C#'s pattern matching would behave as F#'s (i.e. know whether it is exhaustive and give a warning if it's not).

Comment: @Gabriel: C# knows that a switch with a default is exhaustive, but it does *not* know if a switch without a default is exhaustive. For example, C# will flag `int x; bool b = whatever; switch(b) { case true: case false: x = 1; break; } int y = x;` as an "x is used but not definitely assigned" error, even though you and I know that the switch is a no-op.

Comment: @EricLippert any chance the above (ie more exhaustive switch expressions without `default`) will get added to C#? Its honestly my favourite feature in kotlin. And Microsoft research has one of the coolest SMT solvers around: I vote we set compile times ablaze and have the compiler try to reason about the exhaustive-ness of _any_ switch statement! (I requested the same of the kotlin compiler team, they weren't enthusiastic)

Comment: @Groostav: In general we do not want to have rules in the language which could require the compiler to run for arbitrary amounts of time and solve arbitrary hard problems. Unfortunately, overload resolution is already NP-HARD, but we'd rather not make the number of such situations in the compiler larger. Also, you want the rules of the language to be simple and straightforward so that third parties can implement the spec; saying "and then do whatever this version of the SMT solver does" makes that hard on third parties.

Comment: @Groostav: Now, if the proposed feature is to make a *static analyzer* that looks for possibly bad switches, and that analyzer uses whatever proprietary technology it likes, and runs for however long the user wants it to run, then I'm 100% for that. I just don't think that the compiler is the right place to put that sort of tool.

Comment: @Groostav: All that said, I agree with you; having good pattern matching where the compiler is pretty smart about when you've forgotten a case is quite nice. I've been doing a lot of work in OCaml and Scala lately and I do quite like both of their implementations of pattern matching.

Answer (score 3):

Both proposed ways (with `switch`es and `if`s) have the same flaw: each time a new action type is introduced you are obliged to modify the switch or and another else-if construction. You may be OK with it working on a pet project of your own, but it is not an example of a flexible, maintainable design. After a while these switches tend to become really huge and dreadful. And what is even worse is that no one is able to extend you functionality not having an access to your code (i.e. having it referenced as a library).

Keeping in mind [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), try to do the following:

1. Define an interface that all your actions would implement. It may be really simple, like this:

```
    public interface IAction 
    {
        void Do();
    }

    public class RenameAction : IAction
    {
        public readonly int id;
        public readonly string title;

        public RenameAction(int id, string title)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
        }

        public void Do()
        {
            // Perform an action
        }
    }
```

2. The caller class should know nothing about which particular classes are passed into its method: its responsibility is only to run all the actions one by one:

```
    public class ActionExecutor
    {
        // ommit details
        public void Execute(IEnumerable actions)
        {
            foreach (var action in actions)
            {
                action.Do();
            }
        }
    }
```

3. Assuming that different actions may have completely different sets of input parameters, I would suggest introducing abstract factories for them as well:

```
    public interface IActionFactory
    {
        IAction Create();
    }

    public class RenameActionFactory : IActionFactory
    {
        public IAction Create(IDictionary parameters)
        {
            // using a dictionary - is not a best choise. Just an example
            return new RenameAction(parameters["id"], parameters["title"]);
        }
    }
```

4. Then, you have to have some correspondence between action types (they may be defined as `enum` members, or constants mapped to some DB configuration table, or something else) and factories. On of the ways would be have a configuration class

```
    public class ActionFactoriesConfiguration
    {
        private readonly Dictionary _configuration;

        public ActionFactoriesConfiguration()
        {
            _configuration =  new Dictionary
            {
                { ActionType.Rename, RenameActionFactory }
            }
        }

        public Type GetActionFactoryType(ActionType actionType)
        {
            if (_configuration.ContainsKey(actionType))
            {
                return _configuration[actionType];
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Another way would be storing a lambda-functions for each action type. In this case no factories are needed, but the code becomes harder to test.

Another yet way includes using some of the [IoC-frameworks](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx).

5. Finally, to create a factory you may implement another class

```
    public class ActionFactoryResolver
    {
        private readonly ActionFactoriesConfiguration _configuration;

        public ActionFactoryResolver(ActionFactoriesConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IActionFactory CreateFactory(ActionType actionType)
        {
            var factoryType = _configuration.GetActionFactoryType(actionType);
            if (factoryType != null)
                return Activator.CreateInstance(actionType);

            return null;
        }
    }
```

This may seem as a huge overhead for a private project. But the strong side of this approach is that most of the classes are written (and tested) only once and never get changed with new actions adding. So they can be developed independently.